# My friend is quite silly

Tags: riddle, animals

> - You can meet my small friend at -1.
> - You can meet my American friend at -2.
> - You can meet my very rare friend at -3.
> - One of my friends is quite silly.
> - One of my friends is very proud.
> - One of my friends is usually preferred warm, but the opposite is sometimes necessary.
> - One of my friends sometimes sits, but then bad things happen to him.
> - But do not be afraid or you might end up like my silly friend.

Who are we?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your friends are:

> different types of birds

You can meet my small friend at -1.
You can meet my American friend at -2.
You can meet my very rare friend at -3.

> The first three hints are [golf scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf#Scoring_and_handicapping):
>  -1 = **Birdie**
>  -2 = **Eagle** ([American Eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bald_eagle))
>  -3 = **Albatros** (only [18 players](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_professional_golfers_who_have_hit_an_albatross#Major_championships) managed to do this in the history of golf)

One of my friends is quite silly.
One of my friends is very proud.
One of my friends is usually preferred warm, but the opposite is sometimes necessary.
One of my friends sometimes sits, but then bad things happen to him.
But do not be afraid or you might end up like my silly friend.

> The rest are idioms:
>  [Silly goose](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/silly)
>  [Proud as a **peacock**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/peacock)
>  **Turkey** (preferred hot on Christmas, [*cold turkey*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold%20turkey) is the opposite)
>  [Sitting **duck**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sitting+duck)
>  If you're afraid, you might get [goose bumps](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goose%20bumps).

Comment: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cook+goose

Comment: silly might be for chicken, silly chicken is a recipe. Also afraid corresponds to chicken, as in 'chicken out'.

Comment: Silly goose is the correct idiom. Also sorry about the last one. it is not a bird but an extra hint for the silly bird.

Comment: the last hint was goose bumps by the way.